# Stripe ConfirmCardPayment method create a spinner to wait until the result

Tags: javascript, promise, stripe-payments, loader

I wanted to add a loader while stripe's `confirmCardPayment` returns a result. Since the method returns a result object that tells whether the event succeeded or failed. But what is the way to capture the waiting event happening after I click submit. Do I say result.pending or Do I have add a method in the then().

```
stripe
.confirmCardPayment('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', {
 payment_method: {
  card: cardElement,
  billing_details: {
    name: 'Jenny Rosen',
   },
  },
 })
  .then(function(result) {
   // Handle result.error or result.paymentIntent
  });
```

Comment: Are you using a framework or just vanilla JS/jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I am using Js/jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a `loading` variable

```
let loading = false;
function stripepayment() {
   loading = true;
    stripe
.confirmCardPayment('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', {
 payment_method: {
  card: cardElement,
  billing_details: {
    name: 'Jenny Rosen',
   },
  },
 })
  .then(function(result) {
    loading = false;
   // Handle result.error or result.paymentIntent
  });
}
```

then show your loader while the loading is true

ex:

```
{ loading ? <loader /> : null }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is going to depend on how you manage your front-end. If you were to use something like React with hooks, you could also use async/await patterns:

```
const clickHandler = useCallback(async () => {
  if (isLoading) return;

  setIsLoading(true);

  const stripe = await stripePromise;
  const result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', { ... });

  setIsLoading(false);
}, []);
```

Edit: Given your comment about using js/jq, you'd do something more like what @Bhuwan suggested.

```
showPaymentLoader(true);
stripe
  .confirmCardPayment('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', { ... })
  .then( function () {
    showPaymentLoader(false);
  });
```